# Self compiled Perl package Centos

Tags: yum, centos6, perl

I have a Centos 6 server.. I have compiled Perl 5.16 in it (in a non-standard location).

Now when I try to install Some package which is dependent on Perl using yum..

Yum tries to install Perl again.. How do I tell yum to use the installed Perl..

```
FYI:

# perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-multi-ld

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a horrible idea to make system packages use a non-sytem perl, as you'll undoubtedly run into backwards compatibility issues. So you'll need to install your 'Some package' from source as well.

Comment: I was not thinking in that angle... it makes sense.. Thanks for your answer...